# Не находит картинку

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не отображается картинка прилагаю скриншот, путь верный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я в скриншоте ничего не нашёл. Довольно сложно там найти особенно если нет img src или чего-то такого. Сделайте максимум два три тега.

Comment: @nick_n_a - Не совсем понял. Картинка располагается в div.header

Она служит как фоновое изображение

Comment: Нет, путь неверный. В CSS прописан пусть `1/css/img/header.png`, а картинка лежит в `1/img/header.png`, вот и не находит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я даже сейчас вижу что файл header.png находится в паке /1/img/header
но ты ищешь 1/css/img/header

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй путь с: `img/header.png`, на: `../img/header.png`.